# Selectors in Cocos2d schedule method

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, selector

So I am doing this to initialize my selector:

```
//In .h

SEL selectors[3];

//In .m

selectors[0] = @selector(rotate);
selectors[1] = @selector(discharge);
```

And here is the problem:

When I call this in my init method in Cocos2d like this:

```
[self performSelector:selectors[0]];
```

it works fine, but when I call this line of code in a method called moveThings which is invoked through the schedule (`[self schedule:@selector(moveThings:)]`) at the end of my init method in Cocos2d it gives `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. What is the problem with scheduling things?

UPDATE:

I have found there is a problem with the rotate function (the function being stored in selector[0]). Here it is:

```
-(void)rotate:(ccTime)delta {
    if (((CCSprite *)[creature objectAtIndex:0]).rotation < 360) {
        ((CCSprite *)[creature objectAtIndex:0]).rotation++;
    }
    else {
        ((CCSprite *)[creature objectAtIndex:0]).rotation++;
    }
}
```

If I comment the contents of the method out it works fine when called through moveThings and init.

If I change the methods contents with:

```
((CCSprite *)[creature objectAtIndex:0]).rotation++;
```

It fails... But, again, I would like to state that all of these things do work if I call it in my init method, even call it twice in a row, but it will not work (except when I take out the contents of the rotate method) if I call it through the moveThings: method which is being invoke through the schedule method it fails.

Further update:

If I call:

```
((CCSprite *)[creature objectAtIndex:0]).rotation++;
```

In moveThings (which is being, as I've said before, invoked by the `schedule:(SEL)` method) it fails. Where as long as it is not invoked through a method that is the called by schedule it works.

Comment: What does the crash log say actually?

Comment: @Deepak: Sorry, I keep editing it wrong... I didn't paste it, should have... The selector works for moveThings just not selectors[0]...

Comment: @Deepak: The crash log says `Program recieved EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: Which one is failing? `[self schedule:@selector(moveThings:)];` or `[self schedule:selectors[0]];`

Comment: @Deepak: `[self schedule:selectors[0]];` Which is being called inside of the moveThings method.

Comment: Where have you set the `selectors`? And how's your loop implemented in your `moveThings:` method

Comment: @Deepak: The selectors are initialized in the init method. And `[self schedule:@selector(moveThings:)];` Is called at the end of my init method. And the only line of code moveThings has is `[self schedule:selectors[0]];` and moveThings is void type has one argument of type id.

Comment: @Deepak: I'm pretty sure (after doing some poking and prodding) something wrong with my rotate function if you look at my updated answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you call performSelector there are only two options:

1. have your selector take no arguments and leave the ":" off the @selector(foo) definition.
2. have your selector take either one or two arguments **which both must be an NSObject or subclass**

it is the latter that is messing you up here I suspect.

Here are the three forms of `performSelector`:

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object;
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object1 withObject:(id)object2;
```

You'll note that the withObject arguments are all of type `id` which is an Objective C object.

The selector you're trying to use takes a `ccTime` which is a `float` and **not** an Objective C object as it's param and that is why things are crashing:

```
-(void)rotate:(ccTime)delta;
```

One option is to make a wrapper method that takes a wrapped `ccTime` and unwraps it and calls the `rotate:(ccTime)` method:

```
- (void) wrappedRotate: (NSNumber*) inDelta
{
    [self rotate: [inDelta floatValue]];
}
```

then use

```
selectors[0] = @selector(wrappedRotate:);
```

and then call via:

```
[self schedule: @selector(moveThings:)]);  // cocos2d schedule

... 

- (void) moveThings: (ccTime) dt
{
   [self performSelector: selectors[0] withObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: dt]];
  ...
}
```

One reason you are getting confused is because Cocos2d is using @selector in somewhat more complicated ways (see CCScheduler.m in the CCTimer::initWithTarget:selector:interval: and CCTimer::update: method in particular).

disclaimer: code typed into SO so not checked with a compiler, but the essence of what you need should be here.

Comment: +1. The system wants to retain the object that is passed, and doing so on a plain float will crash.

Comment: Thanks, this was one problem, also I forgot to say `self.creature`... Because I only wanted one instance of that...

Answer (score 0):

One problem for sure is that you are using a variable declared inside a `.h` while initializing it inside the relative `.m`. According to the linking I'm not sure that just one variable `selectors` will exist (so that different files that include `.h` will have different versions).

First of all I suggest you to try adding the keyword `extern` to have

```
extern SEL selectors[3];
```

to tell your linker that it is initialized inside the relative `.m` and to use just that one.

Comment: Using extern gives an error... `expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'extern'`.

Comment: It shouldn't, I just tried in XCode, there should be something different. Maybe you are declaring the SEL inside a class? But is it an instance variable or just a variable? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Yes, I was declaring selectors inside a class. And I believe it is an ivar.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems from your method definition which is `- (void)rotate;` and not `- (void)rotate:(ccTime)dt;`

You should adjust your selectors likewise.

Comment: It's not that it wont call it, it's just that when ever I call it through a method that is being invoked with: `[self schedule:(SEL)]` It wont work. If I just call the moveThings method with out the using the schedule method it works, if I perform selectors twice in a row it works also...

Comment: Oops, actually, I have it defined the way you have suggested I changed it too, wrote it wrong in the question...

Comment: Nope... With rotate I am just changing the rotation of the CCSprite using `.rotation = x;` where x is a float to change rotation. I can't use `CCRotateBy` because I need to keep track of the current rotation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

If your method does not have any arguments then do not use a colon in your selector call.

```
// Requires @selector(foo:)
- (void) foo:(id)sender;
// Requires @selector(foo)
- (void) foo;
```